# Clojure Anonymous Functions

Tags: clojure, anonymous-function

I was building a function to put strings inside of vectors.

I can't figure out though, why does this work:

`(mapv (fn [i] [i]) '("hi" "there"))`

but this doesn't work:

`(mapv #([%]) '("hi" "there"))`

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13204993) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4921566).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/fn#example-560054c2e4b08e404b6c1c80

In short: `#(f) == (fn [] (f))`, therefore `#([1 2 3]) == (fn [] ([1 2 3]))`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

[As glts mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038786/clojure-anonymous-functions#comment61627901_37038786), the anonymous function [reader macro](http://clojure.org/reference/reader) wraps its body in a list, like this:

```
(read-string "#([%])")
;=> (fn* [p1__20620#] ([p1__20620#]))
```

Usually for situations where you need to write an anonymous function whose body is a vector, I'd recommend just using the [`fn`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/fn) macro as you've done in your question:

```
(mapv (fn [i] [i]) '("hi" "there"))
;=> [["hi"] ["there"]]
```

In this case, though, your `(fn [i] [i])` is equivalent to the built-in [`vector`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vector) function, so I'd suggest you use that instead:

```
(mapv vector '("hi" "there"))
;=> [["hi"] ["there"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`#()` expects a function as its first argument. You could do `#(vector %)`

e.g:

```
(map #(vector %) (range 5))
> ([0] [1] [2] [3] [4])
```

Of course you could also just do:

```
(map vector (range 5))
> ([0] [1] [2] [3] [4])
```